# When binding to Collection<T>, how to make each view item bound to wrapper object of T

Tags: collectionviewsource

I have a collection (IList) bind to ListView, now, by default Foo is bind to item in the list view, but I want to bind wrapper of (Foo) = Goo to each list view item.

IList is returned from the system API which returns virtualized list of item of Foo, but in my list view item, i want to bind custom object which is a wrapper of Foo=Goo. 
One solution is to create list of Goo from list of Foo, unfortunately that is not possible in this case, any converter approach available in this case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What programming language? Platform?

Comment: Please provide more context of what you're trying to do and the code you have tried, but that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using inheritance such that Foo is the base class and Goo is a subclass that extends Foo.

Comment: I'm using Win 8 metro style app. Getting virtualized vector from system API which returns list of FileInformation, each item of the data template shows rich view; if i am able to get list of my object then it should solve the problem, but i could not get list of my object. I am looking for any way add converter in ItemTemplate which  takes FileInformation object and returns wrapper object.

Comment: DataContext of the each list view item must assign to object of Goo, but i don't know whether it is possible to do?, but currently data source of the listview set to to list of Foo.